# Action dispatch does not change store state. React Native, Redux, Redux Thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Action dispatсh in reducer does not change store state. Everything seems to be correct. The console responds that the reducer is set to action.options. But does not change state.
If you equate action.options to a number or string, then everything is fine. Store is changing. What should I do?

Here is my actions file:

reducer.js

```
import { SENSOR_UI, SENSOR_UI_LENGHT, SENSOR_FETCHED, FONT_LOADED, SENSOR_BUTTON, Routes, EAction } from './types';



const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    fontLoaded: false,
    deviceList: {},
}; 
const initialStateRoutes =
{
    isLoading: false,
    option: [],
}
const apiState = {
    login: "",
    password: "",
}
export function apiReducer (state = initialState, action){
  switch (action.type) {  
    case 'SENSOR_BUTTON':
      console.log("sdsdsddfsdfsdfsd");
      return { ...state, sensor: action.sensor };
    case 'SENSOR_FETCHED':
      return { ...state,
        deviceList: action.deviceList,
        isLoading: true,
       };
    case 'FONT_LOADED':
      return { ...state,
        deviceList: action.deviceList,
        fontLoaded: true,
       };
    case 'SENSOR_FAILED':
      return { ...state, err: action.err };
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
export function auth(state = apiState, action) { 
  switch (action.type) {  
    case EAction.FORM_AUTH_LOGIN_UPDATE:
         return {
            ...state,
            login : action.login
         };
    case EAction.FORM_AUTH_PASSWORD_UPDATE:
         return {
            ...state,
            password : action.password
         };
    case EAction.FORM_AUTH_RESET:
         return {
            ...state,
            login : "",
            password : ""
         };
    case EAction.FORM_AUTH_AUTOFILL:
         return {
            ...state,
            login : action.login,
            password : action.password
         };
    default:
        return state;
  }  
}
export function routes(state=initialStateRoutes, action)
{
  switch (action.type) {  
    case Routes.HOME:
         return {
            ...state,
            login : action.login
         };
    case Routes.DETAIL:
    console.log("success dispath", action.options);
         return {
            ...state,
            sensor : action.sensor,
            option: action.options,
            isLoading: true
         };
    case Routes.Profile:
         return {
            ...state,
            profileInfo : action.profileInfo,
         };
    default:
        return state;
  }  
}
```

actionCreator.js

```
import { merge } from 'react-lodash';
import {
  SEARCH_CHANGE,
  SENSOR_FAILED,
  SENSOR_FETCHED,
  FONT_LOADED,
  SET_SENSOR,
  EAction,
  SENSOR_BUTTON,
  Routes,
} from './types';
import data from '../config.json';

export function errorFetched(err) {
  return { type: SENSOR_FAILED, err };
}
export function setSensorAction(successSensor) {
  return {
    type: SET_SENSOR,
    sensor: successSensor,
  };
}
export function deviceList(success) {
  return { type: SENSOR_FETCHED, deviceList: success };
}
export function fontLoaded() {
  return { type: FONT_LOADED };
}
export function sensorPress(sensor) {
  return { type: SENSOR_BUTTON, sensor: sensor };
}

const cookies = {};

export function loginUpdate(event) {
  return {
    type: EAction.FORM_AUTH_LOGIN_UPDATE,
    login: event,
  };
}
export function passwordUpdate(event) {
  return {
    type: EAction.FORM_AUTH_PASSWORD_UPDATE,
    password: event,
  };
}
export function reset() {
  return {
    type: EAction.FORM_AUTH_RESET,
  };
}
export function tryAutoFill() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    if (
      cookies &&
      cookies.login !== undefined &&
      cookies.password !== undefined
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: EAction.FORM_AUTH_AUTOFILL,
        login: cookies.login,
        password: cookies.password,
      });
    }
  };
}
function auth(route) {
  return NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: route,
  });
}

export function submit() {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    const state = getState();
    if (state.app.login == 'admin' && state.app.password == '123') {
      return dispatch(auth('Home'));
    } else return dispatch(reset());
  };
}
export function onBackPress() {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    const state = getState().nav;
    if (state.index === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
    return true;
  };
}
function info(userInterface, key) {
  const sensorGraph = {};
  const option = userInterface.application.map.rx;
  for (let x = 0; x < key.length; x++) {
    const info = [];
    const empty = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < option[i].options.length; j++) {
        if (option[i].options[j] == key[x]) {
          info.push(option[i]);
          sensorGraph[key[x]] = info;
        }
      }
      if (option[i].options[0] == undefined) {
        empty.push(option[i]);
        sensorGraph['info'] = empty;
      }
    }
  }
  return sensorGraph;
}
function getDetail(sensor, options) {
  return {
    type: Routes.DETAIL,
    options,
    sensor: sensor,
  };
}
export function showDetailSensor(sensor) {
  const config = ['batteryFlag', 'csettingsFlag', 'periodFlag', 'graphFlag'];
  return function(dispatch, setState) {
    let option = info(sensor, config)
    dispatch(auth('Details'));
    return dispatch(getDetail(sensor, option))
  };
}
```

index.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { initialState, auth, apiReducer, routes } from './reducer';
import { navReducer, middleware } from '../screens/AppNavigator';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  app: auth,
  nav: navReducer,
  api: apiReducer,
  rou: routes,
}); 

export const store = createStore(
  appReducer,
  applyMiddleware(middleware, thunk, logger)
);
```

Comment: in your first reducer, you are importing those `types` but still checking for them by `string` values in your `switch/case`. They might still be the same, but you should change them

Comment: I changed, it still does not work. I doubt that because of this it did not work.

A value is sent to the reducer itself, but does nothing with it. I note that if instead of `option` you insert any value, then everything is fine

Comment: sorry, that was not meant to be a solution, just best practice

Comment: I understand the problem is that reducer does not accept two objects. When I combined the objects into one, it all worked out.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the solution is simple. I have everything right. I used logger and tried to catch an error. But it turned out that the logger itself is either with a bug, I do not know what is wrong with it